# Overlook a mistake

Tags: word-usage, phrases, collocations

The word **overlook** has a few meanings. Two of them sound close.

> *to fail to see or notice (something)
>
> to pay no attention to (something)*

(Merriam-Webster's Dictionary)

In the following sentence

> The teacher overlooked the mistake.

Can it mean both:

The teacher didn't notice the mistake.(unintentional)

The teacher ignored the mistake.
(intentional)

depending on the context? Or is it a matter of collocation and *overlook* with *mistake* only means *ignore/forgive*?

Comment: It's context by which you can be sure of that.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. I think we do use _oversight_ in the UK in phrases such as _to have oversight over_ and as an adjective in _oversight committee_

Comment: Afterall, if you are watching from the outside, how would you know if it was accidental or deliberate unless they told you? And if they tell you, they would choose a different word.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it depends on the context. The example sentence you give is *ambiguous*, and could mean either.

I can't think of any particular noun that, when used with "overlook" always means either intentional or unintentional because of convention, rather than because the meaning is obvious from the context itself.